# How to handle autotools project with cmake dependency?

Tags: cmake, autotools

I have an autotools C project that needs to use another library that is built with CMake. Is their an equivalent to  AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS that will work with CMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you want to configure and build the CMake-based project as part of configuring and building the Autotools-based host project.  This is possible, and there are several viable ways to do it, but I'm not aware of anything wholly pre-packaged like `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` is for Autotools-based subprojects.

### For configuration

#### Option 1 - config commands

Autoconf provides [a group of macros](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Commands.html#index-AC_005fCONFIG_005fCOMMANDS-225) by which you can specify custom commands for `configure` or the generated `config.status` script to run.  You could use one of these -- probably `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS`, but maybe `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS_POST` -- to run `cmake` (and any wanted preparatory steps) in the subproject.  Personally, I like this option best.

#### Option 2 - glue script

`AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` instructs `configure` to run `configure` scripts in the specified subsirectories, but those other `configure` scripts don't need to be Autotools-generated.  You could conceivably write a custom wrapper script named "`configure`" in the subproject directory for the parent `configure` to run, but which itself performs an appropriate call to `cmake`.  `AC_CONFIG_SUBDIRS` in the top-level configuration should then run that script at the right time.

#### Option 3 - custom code

I think Autoconf already provides sufficient support for what you seem to want, but if you think otherwise then you always have the option of writing whatever shell code you want into `configure` via `configure.ac`.  You might find it worthwhile to write a custom macro for that, especially if you have multiple CMake subprojects, but that's not obligatory.  Note that such commands are distinguished from those specified via `AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS` & co. by the timing of their execution.

### For building

Presumably you'll be relying on recursive `make` during the build and installation steps.  It shouldn't be hard to make that work, whether you're using an Automake-based `Makefile.in` or a hand-rolled one at the top level.

#### Option 1 - Automake + glue makefile

Use a `SUBDIRS` variable in your top-level `Makefile.am` to direct `make` to recurse into the CMake project's subdirectory, just as you would do into any other project's.  Write a simple Makefile there that recurses into a `build` subdirectory (which you will have had to ensure is created and configured by `configure`).  This should not collide with the subproject because it presupposes that a separate build directory is used.  The glue makefile can adapt targets and `make` variables to the expectations of the subproject's build system.

The Automake documentation describes [all the recursive targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Third_002dParty-Makefiles.html#Third_002dParty-Makefiles) that the top-level Autotools makefile might try to build recursively, and the glue makefile should provide all of them -- though there may be many that need only a dummy (but not empty) recipe.

#### Option 2 - hand-rolled top-level `Makefile.in`

If, on the other hand, you're using a hand-rolled top-level `Makefile` template then you have full control over your recursive `make` invocations.  You could still use a glue makefile in the subproject in this case, but it's probably easier and cleaner to just adapt directly to the expected CMake-generated makefile.

Comment: How exactly would I do the first option for config? I've tried adding:
AC_CONFIG_COMMANDS([libdivsufsort], [cd libdivsufsort; cmake .]) 
But it looks like the cmake command is never ran.

Comment: That looks right to me, @razeh, and an analogous usage works fine for me in a test project.  At or near the end of `configure`'s output, you should see a line something like "config.status: executing libdivsufsort commands".  If you do not see that, then you probably forgot to run `autoreconf` after applying the change.  If you *do* see it, then perhaps you misspelled the directory name, or `cmake` failed for some reason.  Or note that you'd need somewhat cleverer commands if you're trying to configure for an out-of-source build.